# How to fix a bug in live search?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

there is a live search code (I didn't write it), it worked fine, but recently an error appeared, I don't understand how to fix it and what can be done?
code:

```
export async function liveSearch() {
    const searchForms = document.querySelectorAll('.search-form');

    searchForms.forEach(searchForm => {
        const searchAll = searchForm.querySelectorAll('.search-form__input');
        const results = searchForm.querySelector('.search-form__result');

        let searchTerm = "";

        async function showList(searchTerm) {
            let searchJSON = await umi_macro('search', 'smart_search', [searchTerm], null, false);
            searchJSON = Object.values(searchJSON)
            if (searchJSON == ['search', 'smart_search']) {
                searchJSON = []
            }
            results.innerHTML = "";
            searchJSON
                .filter((item) => {
                    
                    return (
                        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                        item.link.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                        item.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                    );
                })
                .forEach((e) => {
                    const li = document.createElement("li");
                    const name = e.name
                    let str = insertMark(name, name.indexOf(searchTerm), [...searchTerm].length)

                    li.innerHTML = `
                    <a class="search-form__link ${e.type === 'category' ? 'red' : ''}" href="${e.link}" title="${name}">${str}</a>`;
                    results.appendChild(li);
                });
            console.log(results)
            results.classList.add("active");
        };


        const inputCheckHandler = debounce(showList, 1500);

        for (let search of [...searchAll]) {
            search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                if (typeof search.value  === 'string'){
                searchTerm = search.value.toLowerCase().trim();
                inputCheckHandler(searchTerm);
                }
            });
        }

        function insertMark(searchString, searchPosition, searchLength) {
            let result;
            if (searchPosition === -1) {
                result =
                    `<mark>${searchString.slice(0, searchPosition + searchLength + 1)}</mark>${searchString.slice(searchLength)}`
            } else {
                result =
                    `${searchString.slice(0, searchPosition)}<mark>${searchString.slice(searchPosition, searchPosition + searchLength)}</mark>${searchString.slice(searchPosition + searchLength)}`
            }
            return result;
        }

        document.addEventListener('click', closeSearch)
        function closeSearch(e) {
            let target = e.target;

            if (!target.closest('.header__search-form') && results) {
                results.classList.remove("active");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and a error:
https://gyazo.com/8753a3ab0495d827f97eef07c5b010e3

when you click on it, the console displays:
https://gyazo.com/220194ae821ca67322ef8ac5582780dc

I wrote the toString() method, tried to convert it to a string, it didn't help, before that the console was swearing at toLowerCase()
Please help me figure this out, thank you.

Comment: At the very least, check if the value exists in the first place before calling a method on it like `toLowerCase()` or your own `toString()` method. This may not fix the ultimate problem but it's your first step, along with some logs.